# Servicio de Angular no me devuelve la información de mi base de datos en firebase

Tags: sql, angular, firebase, where

En mi componente Lista.component tengo lo siguiente:

constructor(public auth: AuthService, firestore: AngularFirestore, private _rifasservice: RifasService, private router: Router){ }

ngOnInit(): void{

```
this.auth.user$.subscribe(userProfile =>{
  this.userlogemail=userProfile?.email;
  alert(this.userlogemail)
  this.getRifas(this.userlogemail)
})
```

******y la función donde paso el "email" del usuario logueado******

getRifas(userlogemail:any){

```
this._rifasservice.getRifa(userlogemail).subscribe(data=> {

  this.fechaactual=new Date().toISOString().split('T').shift();
  

  if (this.rifas){this.borifas=true}
  this.rifas=[];
  data.forEach ((element:any) => {
    this.rifas.push({
      id: element.payload.doc.id,
      ...element.payload.doc.data()
    })

});
```

Y en el servicio tengo lo siguiente:

getRifa(userlogemail:any): Observable {

```
return this.firestore.collection ('BaseRifas', ref => ref.where('userlog',"==",'userlogemail')).snapshotChanges()
```

}

Si en lugar de la variable 'userlogemail', pongo directamente un email, si que me trae toda la información.

¿Alguien podría ayudarme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el método `getRifa` del servicio, estás comparando el valor de la propiedad 'userlog' con la cadena literal `'userlogemail'`, en lugar de usar la variable `userlogemail` que pasas como parámetro.

Para corregir este problema, debes modificar la consulta dentro del método `getRifa` del siguiente modo:

```
getRifa(userlogemail:any): Observable<any> {
  return this.firestore.collection('BaseRifas', ref => ref.where('userlog', '==', userlogemail)).snapshotChanges();
}
```

Aquí, en lugar de `'userlogemail'` entre comillas simples, utilizamos la variable `userlogemail` que pasamos como parámetro a la función. Además, he incluido el tipo de retorno como Observable `<any>`.

Con esta modificación, debería funcionar correctamente y traer los datos de la colección filtrados por el valor de `userlog` igual al valor de `userlogemail`.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, ahora funciona perfectamente!!! le di mil vueltas... Muchas gracias

Comment: De nada! Para eso esta la comunidad